# Modx. Слетела админка после запуска скрипта. При попытке зайти через мой_сайт/manager выдает белый экран

Tags: modx, админка

Я пыталась запустить приложение modalconsole, поэтому создала пункт меню с действием core/components/modalconsole/elements/plugins/plugin.modalconsole.php. После того, как я прошла по этому пункту меню, браузер выдал белый экран, и продолжает выдавать. Пробовала перезайти (удалила в БД сессию), после входа в админку снова белый экран. Что делать?

Comment: Если имеете доступ к файлам, попробуйте удалить файлы кеша в /core/cache/, все содержимое этой папки. И после этого еще раз попробовать /manager/

Comment: @AntonTarasov я уже пробовала

Answer (score 0):

Решила проблему, загрузив резервную копию с хостинга, сделанную, когда все работало.